# Package java.text - where can I search for it?

Tags: java, install.packages

When I try to run my program, I get following message:

```
PS C:\Users\.....> import java.text.NumberFormat;
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What can be wrong?

I wonder if it is because I do not have java.text with NumberFormat?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't tell.  You have incorrect or incomplete Java syntax. 
 `java.text` is part of Java.  Edit your question to include the code you've written as text.

Comment: Based on `C:\Users.....> import java.text.NumberFormat;` it looks like you are trying to execute `import java.text.NumberFormat;` as *command* in console and errors informs you that console doesn't recognize `import` as valid command (not that there is a problem with `java.text` package). It is hard to explain why you end up in such state without *specific* description of steps necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are you running (starting) this program of yours? Has it been compiled?